# Find the perfect squares of four digits whose square root is the sum of the numbers obtained if we separate the first two digits from the last two

Tags: radicals, square-numbers, decimal-expansion

**the question**

We are asking for the perfect squares of four digits whose square root is the sum of the numbers obtained if we separate the first two digits from the last two

**the idea**

let the number be $\overline{abcd}$, where a,b,c,d are digits

$32^2\leq \overline{abcd} \leq 99^2$, which means $32\leq \sqrt{\overline{abcd}
} \leq 99$

I don't really understand the part with 'sum'... there are 2 or more numbers to add? Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: I think they mean $\sqrt{\overline{abcd}} = \overline{ab} + \overline{cd}$.

Comment: Let the four-digit number be $1000a+100b+10c+d$. They are saying $1000a+100b+10c+d = (10(a+c)+b+d)^2$. Should be a messy equation to directly solve. Instead, you can make some observations on the digits.

Comment: Find integer solutions to $(x+y)^2 = 100x + y$. What approaches would you use?  $\quad$ Note: We have solutions like 2035, 3025.

Answer (score 1):

A necessary condition is to find positive integer solutions to $(x+y)^2 = 100x +y$, subject to $32 \leq x+y \leq 99$.

Writing this as $ (x+y)(x+y-1) = 99 x $, since $ \gcd(x+y, x+y - 1) = 1$, conclude that we must have:

- $x+y \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{9}$
- $x+y \equiv 0, 1 \pmod {11}$

Thus, we get that
$ x+y \equiv 0, 1, 45, 55 \pmod{99}$.

Finally, verify that $x+y = 45, 55, 99$ satisfy the conditions.
Note: In the verification, we have to show that $ x, y$ are integers from 0 to 100. In particular, this implies that $\lfloor \frac{ (x+y)^2}{100} \rfloor = x$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if there is an algorithm to find striaghtforwardly the solution it is difficult to find out it. So we try to reduce the $68$ possibilities to a smaller number.

Let $X, A, B$ integers such that $$\begin{cases}X^2=100A+B\\X=A+B\end{cases}\Rightarrow A=\frac{X(X-1)}{99}$$ then, because of the factor $11$, the integer $A$ is among the following fourteen possibilities:
$$\frac{33\times32}{99}\space\space\text { or }\space\space\frac{34\times33}{99}\\\frac{44\times43}{99}\space\space\text { or }\space\space\frac{45\times44}{99}\\\frac{55\times54}{99}\space\space\text { or }\space\space\frac{56\times55}{99}\\\frac{66\times65}{99}\space\space\text { or }\space\space\frac{67\times66}{99}\\\frac{77\times76}{99}\space\space\text { or }\space\space\frac{78\times77}{99}\\\frac{88\times87}{99}\space\space\text { or }\space\space\frac{89\times88}{99}\\\frac{99\times98}{99}\space\space\text { or }\space\space\frac{100\times99}{99}$$
Only $\dfrac{45\times44}{99}=20,\dfrac{55\times54}{99}=30,\dfrac{99\times98}{99}=98$ are integers as desired, of two digits (the other eleven quantities are fractional excepting the last equal to $100$). Inside of them are explicitly listed
the only three solutions $\boxed{X=45,55,99}$

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the word "disguise" is offensive? How are you interpreting it? $\quad$ EG would it be different if I said "just be explicit about that instead of trying to present it as a clever argument"?

Comment: @Calvin Lin: What does mean in English "...... instead of trying to present it as a clever argument"?.  A second question: Why didn't you post your answer before mine? (I could say, like you to me "...instead of trying to present it as a distinct of mine")

Comment: Your solution seemed (at least to me, and possibly you, based on your now-deleted comments) presenting "hey, if we consider the units digit, then we get valuable information about the cases".  As I dug into it, I felt that wasn't the case. I'm fine with a solution that is "try all cases, after all there is only 68 of them", though would hope that such a solution was upfront about its  approach instead of further breaking it down into several cases without a clear advantage of doing so (EG If conditioning on $d=1$ made the casework easy).

Comment: 2/ I did originally leave my solution as a comment right after my first comment, but then decided to post it as a solution to keep this comment stream focused on your callout that my comment was offensive, and that I'm having some (superiority?) complex. $\quad$ Because of the QSBS guidelines, I've been refraining from posting solutions, esp if OP doesn't show their work or further engage. Though, if there are solutions posted, and I feel like I can present a different/better approach, I often end up doing so. I do consider my approach distinct from yours, even though it starts out the same.