# Prove $\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b} \geq \frac{(x + y)^2}{a + b}$, with $x, y, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a, b > 0$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove $\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b} \geq \frac{(x + y)^2}{a + b}$, with $x, y, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a, b > 0$

**Proof**:

$\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b} \geq \frac{(x + y)^2}{a + b}$

$\iff (bx^2 + ay^2)(a + b) \geq ab(x^2 + 2xy + y^2)$

$\iff abx^2 + a^2y^2 + b^2x^2 + aby^2 \geq abx^2 + 2abxy + aby^2$

$\iff a^2y^2  + b^2x^2 \geq 2abxy$

$\iff (ay - bx)^2 \geq 0$

This result prompted me to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove the statement directly $LHS \geq RHS$. However, I couldn't seem to figure out a solution in this manner. I wondered if somebody here has a solution that doesn't involve going backward like above.

Comment: You do have an identity! What do you want to make otherwise?. Perhaps a (without interest) way could be to verify that if $0\lt c\lt a+b$ then all point distinct of origin in the ligne $ay=bx$ does not satisfy your inequality and it still is valid for all $c\gt a+b$.

Comment: @Piquito Hi, I was looking for a solution in which we start from somewhere (with good motivation), and gradually work to the final inequality, instead of going from the inequality to a true identity. This is just my curiosity and I was hoping such a solution might increase my proficiency in these problems.

Comment: It is a good idea in order to improve your proficiency in these problems. Good luck.

Comment: Are you familiar with Titu's lemma?

Comment: @Calvin Lin: I have deleted my reply to you in  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4875063/find-the-perfect-squares-of-four-digits-whose-square-root-is-the-sum-of-the-numb/4875516#4875516  because I have read  Klein instead of Lin. I am not agree with your  your use of the word "disguised" because it was offensive really. What kind of complexes do you suffer from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct Cauchy-Schwarz would be a single step

$$({x\over\sqrt{a}}\sqrt{a}+{y\over\sqrt{b}}\sqrt{b})^2\le({x^2\over a}+{y^2\over b})(a+b)$$

Simplification gives the required inequality

Comment: Woaaaa this is geniusss!

Answer (score 1):

Let Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz run over
$$(x + y)^2\:=\: \left(\sqrt{a}\,\frac{x}{\sqrt a} \,+\, \sqrt{b}\,\frac{y}{\sqrt b}\right)^2$$
(and eventually divide by $a+b\,$).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is so slick! I accepted the other answer as it appeared higher on the page but I understand yours is the same. Hope you don't mind! Thank you again!

Comment: That's fine. If you @ten_to_tenth  had ordered the answers by "Date created (oldest first)" then you'd have caught mine as I posted first, only a tiny bit earlier, sort of random.

Comment: You @ten_to_tenth are in fact considering Titu's lemma, also mentioned in a comment above, or Engel's form of the Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality, cf [CBS - Engel/Titu/Bergström](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Special_cases) .
These are *equivalent formulations* of the CBS inequality, i. e., Engel's form implies CBS.
You asked for "CBS $\implies$ Engel/Titu".